# Running "hem build" on SpineJS does nothing

Tags: npm, spine.js

I've followed this tutorial

http://spinejs.com/mobile/docs/index

And, well, there is no application.js file.

Missing on this documentation, it seems I should run

```
hem build
```

to the *.coffee files be compiled to application.js, but if I run it all I get is a message
"Build application"

And nothing happens...

Any idea?

Running under Mac OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but under Ubuntu. Try uninstalling hem and installing an older version, 0.2.7 did the job.

Use:

`npm install -g hem@0.2.7`